# How to make tee not break lines at window width in powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell

Currently I'm doing the following command to look through all files in a folder for a string, and then `tee` that line to a file:

```
ls -r [folder] | sls "dummy text" | tee dummy.file
```

These lines of text are long and may look like

```
 123445678461454516132113213213214dummy textsadawgwgabagga
```

When I use the command in powershell, if the screen isn't big enough it shows up to me as, for example,

```
123445678461454516132113213213214dummy 
textsadawgwgabagga
```

Which is fine in powershell, but what I don't get is that it writes it to the file like that (I can see why, I guess, as it probably pipes each line to tee individaully based on how it splits it).

Is there any way to get this to `tee` to the file all on one line?

EDIT: doing the following works, but I'd rather use tee if possible to see it in the console

```
ls -r | sls | out-file -width 1000 dummy.file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the way the `MatchInfo` object returned by `select-string` is being output. If you just extract the `Line` property from the matchinfo object, (in which case you are outputting strings and not MatchInfo objects) you should get the behavior you want:

```
ls -r [folder] | sls "dummy text" | select -expand Line | tee dummy.file
```